# Program to send beacons each 15 seconds

Tags: software, ping

I am looking for the tray-minimizable program, which sends an HTTP request to my server each 15 seconds immitating user activity.

Comment: Um…why? This sounds like one of those "there's probably something better except you're not saying what you're actually trying to do" situations.

Comment: This reminds of the 90's, dialup 28.8k and mouse moving programs.

Answer (score 1):

http://phantomjs.org/ This will provide all you need!

You could also use a ping service such as Pingdom.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Any site monitoring application will probably do well for this.  The problem of using your system tray is that your windows system could go down.  You could setup a cron job on an inexpensive linux server just to wget a page every 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty popular service to monitor your websites uptime. https://www.pingdom.com/

> Uptime and performance monitoring made easy Be the first to know when
>   your website is down. Get downtime alerts. Get troubleshooting help.
>   Get uptime & performance report